# c# HTTP Multipart MIME parser

Tags: c#, mime, multipart

I'm getting a Multipart MIME response from an HTTP call and need to extract the parts. I'm looking for a simple way to do this.

I'm using the System.Net.Http methods to get the content, however extracting the response parts is confusing me.

```
HttpClient zClient = new HttpClient();
Uri zAddress = new Uri("http://someDomain.com");

HttpContent content = new StringContent(sb.ToString());
HttpResponseMessage response = zClient.PostAsync(zAddress, content).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // This returns true
    bool zIsMime = response.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent();

    // How do I get the message parts here. This ReadAsMultipartAsync method is confusing me. 
    ReadAsMultipartAsync(HttpContent) ???? 

}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MultipartMemoryStreamProvider zMIME = await response.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
```

Was the simple step I was looking for.